# Why do I get different results when I apply sizeof operator?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sizeof

I have this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char arr[100];
   printf("%d", (int)sizeof(0,arr));
}
```

This prints 4 when compiled as a C file and prints 100 as a C++ file. Why? I am using gcc.

Comment: Note that the only reason to use the comma operator is to produce a side effect of evaluation, but the expression of a `sizeof` operation is not evaluated.

Comment: A declared array is decayed to a pointer in *every* occasion in C, *except* when it appears as operand of `sizeof` or the `&`-operator. In your case, that's not the case, hence it's converted to a pointer. In C++, the array is converted only if needed.

Comment: An excellent example of why compiling C with a C++ compiler is a misguided practice.

Comment: Using the comma operator like this (or in almost any other way) is a misguided practice.

Comment: The real question is "[why are you trying to mix two languages in a single source file?](http://jquelin.blogspot.com/search/label/polyglot)"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In C the result of the right hand operand of the comma operator has a type and **value**. In C  a comma operator does not yield an lvalue. So there is an lvalue to rvalue conversion resulting in decay of array type to pointer type. So in C what you get is the result of `sizeof(char*)`.

In C++ the result of a comma expression is an lvalue. There is no such conversion[as in C] and what you get is the `sizeof(arr)` i.e 100

Comment: That's a pretty sweet answer, I had no idea that behaviour existed in C.

Comment: Even if the comma operator yielded an lvalue in C, it would still print `100`. Because the right operand of the comma operator in his case is a non-lvalue `char*`.

Comment: Yes, the array-decay rules specify that this decay happens as soon as the array name is used except as an operand of `&` or `sizeof`. Since it's being used as an operand of `,` (the comma operator), it has already decayed, regardless of whether `,` preserves lvalues.

Comment: The answer doesn't explain why the result is different in C when `sizeof` is directly applied, as that's an expression also.  The explanation is: there is a specific exception in the conversion rules for `sizeof`. That exception does not exist in C++, no doubt because the conversion rules are different.

Answer (score 3):

#### `sizeof` is an operator not a function

So, you are executing the comma operator, which returns the right operand as its result.

In C++, this is a reference, so it's still an array and has its full size.

In C, in an expression (anything with an operator) normally the type `array of x` is converted to `pointer to x`. But there is a specific exception for two operators: `sizeof` and `&`.

So it matters if `sizeof` gets there first or not, because of the exception to the conversion rules. (See C99 section 6.3.2.1.<sup>†</sup>)

You can see this another way, and here the program returns the same thing in C and C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char arr[100];

  printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof arr);
  printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(arr + 0));
  return 0;
}
```

result on my Mac:

```
100
8
```

---

<sup>†  6.3.2.1(3) Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a
string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is
converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points to the initial element of
the array object and is not an lvalue.</sup>

Comment: "in C++ this is a reference"  - you mean "this is an lvalue"; expressions never have reference type