# Behavior of "comma" operator in sizeof() operator In C

Tags: arrays, c, sizeof, c11, comma-operator

I wrote the code about `sizeof` operator. If I write something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a[20];
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
20 // Ok, it's fine
```

But, If I use the **comma** operator like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char a[20];
    char b;
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(b, a));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
8 // Why the output 8?
```

So, I have a questions:

- Why does compiler give an output `8` in second example?
- What is the behavior of `comma` operator into `sizeof()` operator?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The comma operator has no special meaning to `sizeof`.

`sizeof(b, a)`  examines the complete expression `(b, a)`, works out the resultant type, and computes the size of that type without actually evaluating `(b , a)`.   As noted by chqrlie in comments, the `()` are part of the expression for which the size (of the result) is evaluated.

In this case, `b` is a `char` and `a` is an array.    If the expression `b, a` was to be evaluated, `b` would be evaluated first, the result discarded.   Then `a` would converted to a pointer (`char *`) with value equal to `&a[0]` which would be the result of the expression `(b, a)`.

Since the result of `b, a` is of type `char *`,  `sizeof(b,a)` is equal to `sizeof (char *)`.   That is an implementation defined value but, for your compiler, has a value of `8`   (which probably means the code is being built as a 64-bit application).

Comment: *`sizeof(b, a)` examines the complete expression `b, a`*... Technically, `sizeof(b, a)` examines the complete expression `(b, a)`. But interestingly and confusingly enough, `sizeof((a))` would still produce a value of `20`.

Comment: `sizeof(b, a) examines the complete expression b, a` I think the parenthesis are the first evaluated and then sizeof will evaluate the result. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Michi parentheses (in this context) are not an operator

Comment: @M.M I never said that :). I was speaking about what happens inside those parenthesis and this is first evaluated and only after SIZEOF evaluates the result. Or I'm wrong.

Comment: @M.M Any way [this was my point](https://ideone.com/ijUcKz), when I said that first will be the content of those parenthesis evaluated and then `sizeof` evaluates the result.

Comment: True-   `sizeof(b,a)` evaluates the size of the result from the expression `(b,a)`.  Syntactically `sizeof(int)` requires the `()` around the type name (so `sizeof int` is invalid) while `sizeof expression` does not require `()` and the `()`, if used, are part of the expression.  I'll edit to reflect that shortly.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 11):

In most cases, arrays decay into pointers. So the type of `b,a`  with a comma operator is a `char*` (not a `char[20]` anymore). And pointers are 8 bytes on your machine.

BTW, I think that using `sizeof` on some comma operator is really confusing to the reader. I recommend using `sizeof` on simple expressions or on types.

<sup>(and I just discovered this is one of the tricky differences between C and C++; see [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5766397/841108))</sup>

Comment: Reference is C11 6.3.2.1/3: "Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points
to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue."

Comment: This is a wonky issue, but the fact that there is the comma operator and a sequence point between evaluation of `b` and `a` may cause conflict with that reference C11 6.5.17/2 Comma operator. I don't know the answer, but it seems that `a` would be converted to a pointer if `b` is evaluated as a void pointer injecting a sequence point.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin neither b nor a is evaluated, since they are part of the operand of sizeof.  Sequence points have nothing to do with this

Comment: C11 6.5.17/3 says a comma operator cannot appear as arguments to a function. Now `sizeof` isn't per se a function. I'll certainly defer to your interpretation here. I don't know, but want to make sure I clearly understand -- and with the competing comments and answer -- I do not :(  And all I can do is read, the standard says "*The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression*"... "*Then the right operand is evaluated;*"

Comment: *"this explanation"* is sitting on an exact duplicate. Why didn't you vote to close?

Answer (score 4):

C language is an *lvalue-discarding* language. Comma operator in C does not yield an lvalue and does not preserve "arrayness" of arrays. This means that when right-hand side operand is an array, it is immediately subjected to array-to-pointer conversion. For this reason in C the result of your comma operator is an rvalue of type `char *`. This is what you apply your `sizeof` to. And this is why you get `8` as the result, which is pointer size on your platform.

C++ language is an *lvalue-preserving* language. The right-hand operand of comma operator in C++ is *not* subjected to lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and, in case the operand is an array, it maintains its lvalueness and its array type. In C++ the result of your comma operator is an lvalue of type `char[20]`. This is what you apply your `sizeof` to. And this is why you get `20` as the result.

Comment: The whole story here is because of those parenthesis and has nothing to do with sizeof operator. like I said in my comment, if you do `int a = (1,2,3);` it works but if you do `int a = 1,2,3;` it will not because of the missing of those parenthesis. I think you know way.

Comment: @Michi: It is true that "parenthesis has nothing to do with sizeof operator". But I don't see the importance of this in this context. The code compiles - that's given.

Comment: the whole point here is that people should stop treating SIZEOF operator as a function and they can avoid a thing like this. They are concentrate only on SIZEOF and not what exactly is on the right side.

Comment: @Michi: "Avoid"? Avoid what exactly? I don't see anything in this topic intended to persuade anyone to "avoid" anything. The question is rather technical and neutral. The author is well-aware of the fact that `,` in this context is a *comma operator*, not function argument separator.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that difference between C and C++. Learned something today :-)

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` determines the size by the type of it's operand. In `sizeof(a)`, `a` will not decay to pointer to it's first element and the type of `a` will be `char[20]`. While in `sizeof(b, a)`, `a` is the right operand of comma operator and in this context it will decay to pointer to it's first element and the type of the expression `b , a` would be `char *`. Therefore, `sizeof(b, a)` will return size of `char *` data type.

In C++, result of `,` operator is an lvalue (unlike in C where it yields an rvalue). In that case `sizeof(b, a)` will return the size of array `a`.

Comment: @chqrlie; Oops! Thanks for picking it out.